# How to determine whether a command is running or not from bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to re-run a file php every time it ends...

Then I have created i file SH like this

```
VAR_1=1;

while [[ $VAR_1 != "2" ]]; do

    for filename in *.php; do

        if [ -- check if command is NOT running -- ]; then
            sleep .5
            php $filename
        fi

    done
done
```

What kind of IF i must use ?

Comment: What is the output of the php process? Use that to determine when to re-run that file!

Answer (score 2):

use `pgrep`

```
if ! pgrep -f "php $filename"; then echo "command not running"; fi
```

However, "I want to re-run a file php every time it ends", so why don't you just do this:

```
while true; do
    php "$filename"
done
```

Then you don't have to search for it, when it ends it will just run again.

Comment: with while true, I have hundreds of php running...

Comment: how do I suppress pgrep output?

Comment: Why, does `php` not stay in the foreground when running? You could just redirect stdout `1>` to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

```
( readlink /proc/*/exe | grep -q '/path/to/the/command' )
```

Will return 0 if a process is running `/path/to/the/command`.

However, the canonical way to do this is a bit different:

- On startup, the process checks if some known file (typically `/run/$commandname.pid`) exists
- If so, it reads the PID in it, and check if said process is still running (for instance, there is a `/proc/$pid/` directory)
- If yes, it exits
- Otherwise (no PID file, or process no longer running), it writes its own PID in the file and starts.